# How do I load functions from a configs/<site>/wiki_config.pm file into current Perl script?

Tags: perl, plugins, configuration, require

Let me be more specific.

I'm maintaining a bunch of wiki websites. Each wiki website has a configuration in `configs/wiki_website/wiki_config.pm`. This configuration file contains functions and variables that make each website work the way it has to work.

Here is an example wiki config for "`devs`". It's located in `configs/devs/wiki_config.pm`.

```
package devs;

use warnings;
use strict;


sub log_file {
    return "/var/log/devs/log-%Y-%M-%d.log"
}

sub contact_emails {
    return ("email@gmail.com", "anotheremail@gmail.com")
}

sub public_access {
    1;
}

1;
```

Now what I'm trying to do is load this config in my Perl script:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my $site = shift() || die "No site specified!"

my $config = require "configs/$site/wiki_config.pm"

foreach ($config->contact_emails()) {
   /* email contact_email */
}
```

This doesn't quite work. I'm out of ides how to load `configs/$site/wiki_config.pm` in my Perl script so I could access per-site configuration details. This problem seems almost like one where you have to have plugins. But I can't figure it out either given my directory structure.

Does anyone know how I could load the config file so I could access functions and variables in it?

PS. This question is not related to web programming but is a general quersion about Perl.

Comment: for one thing, your sample code needs more semicolons

Answer (score 1):

First of all this line is wrong, because symbol @ interpolate as array in double quotes.

```
return ("email@gmail.com", "anotheremail@gmail.com");
```

You should to update it to:

```
return ("email\@gmail.com", "anotheremail\@gmail.com");
```

When you store config like this, it equal 1.
    my $config = require "configs/$site/wiki_config.pm" li

***CONFIG***

```
package config;
use strict;

require Exporter;
use base qw(Exporter);
use vars qw(@EXPORT @ISA);

@EXPORT = qw(log_file contact_emails public_access);

sub log_file {
    return "/var/log/devs/log-%Y-%M-%d.log"
}

sub contact_emails {
    return ("email\@gmail.com", "anotheremail\@gmail.com")
}

sub public_access {
    1;
}

1;
```

**MAIN**

```
use strict;
use config;

print contact_emails();
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for corrections and the answer. However my problem is that I don't have one "config", I've one-config-per-site. So I can't do `require config`. I've it in `configs/site/wiki_config.pm`. Also there are many various configs for various parts of services. Such as `configs/site/admin_config.pm`, `configs/site/logger_config.pm`, and others. The `site` in each path changes depending on wiki. There are a lot of wiki's, for example `devs`, `marketing`, `research`, `labs`, and many others.

Comment: If you add the `Exporter` stuff from this answer to your example and add use the `import` method to get to the subs: `no strict 'refs'; my $config = 'dev'; $config->import(qw(log_file)); print log_file();` it will work.